# DBFit : Test that executes other tests

Tags: dbfit

I have a bunch of tests that run individually and I would like to create one single test (let's call it root test) which will call the others one by one, so as I have the complete test suite able to run with a single click and have the results for all of them in a single page, respecting the fact that I want them to be in separate folders, etc.
So my question is: Is there a way to create such a test in DBFit?

Comment: Tell us what've you tried already?

Comment: Hi Paul, I just realized that the suite property along with the !see command allows me to create what I needed.
So I have both a testing suite and my tests isolated!

Comment: you should add it as answer to this question, so someone next can use it :)

Comment: You're right Paul. Well I have a root directory for my tests called 'MyTests' and there are lets say 5 different tests in there in separate folders. I created a suite and I changed the context.txt file of the MyTests page where I would like to run the suite. In that file I added the line 
!see .MySuite?suite
 The suite contains calls to each report I want in its own content.txt file.

Comment: Still, you can add it as answer, and accept it as "one that helped you" - read more here http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a root directory for my tests called 'MyTests' and there are lets say 5 different tests in there in separate folders. I created a suite and I changed the context.txt file of the MyTests page where I would like to run the suite. In that file I added the line !see .MySuite?suite The suite contains calls to each report I want in its own content.txt file.